# Jquery CSS Psuedo Element :ui-dialog

Tags: jquery, css

From what I can see ui:dialog isnt a standard psuedo css element, so I was wondering what the following line achieved:

```
$j("#inline:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");
```

I could find a div with id "inline" but where does the ui-dialog come from ?

Comment: Probably from: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/
I'm right or I missed something?

Comment: Where did you get that code from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.widget()` provides a pseudo-selector for your widget automatically. The pseudo-selector is created from the jQuerySubclass, the namespace and the call name.

```
$.widget('ui.mywidget',{});
// same like this
$.widget('jQuery.ui.mywidget',{});
```

The associated speudo-selector is:

```
':ui-mywidget'
```

Which means every widget created using `$.widget()` automatically provides a pseudo selector.

Here is a [reference](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/tips-for-developing-jquery-ui-widgets/).

Answer (score 0):

The jquery UI widget factory has [automatic pseudo selector generation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js#L36) for all widgets.